# Limit wifi network access per-user with user switching

Tags: macos, network, wifi, keychain

I have a machine running Mavericks shared between two users. One user "Foo" should have access to a network, "Private network A" and another user "Bar" should not. Both users may access "Trusted network B".

I have removed the stored password for "Private network A" from the system keychain and moved it to "Foo"'s keychain.

However, when "Foo" switches to "Bar" using user switching, the connection to "Private network A" is maintained. Is there a way to force the network to disconnect on user switch?

Edit: This happens if user Foo logs out first and then user Bar logs in.

Comment: Does the same happen when you log the user out instead of switching?

Comment: It does. I've updated the main post with this information. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use fast user switching?

Comment: The problem is the same for login/logout AND fast user switching.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to disconnect and reconnect using an AppleScript firing a shell command such as this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031206194417678

Comment: The problem is getting it to run on user switch.